# Simpletest and debug drupal on remote host

Tags: debugging, drupal, windows-7, xdebug, simpletest

I have 2 questions:
1. I see many times in drupal6 .test files and there is weird test code there, what is this? And what is supposed to do, and how i use that (should i?)

1. my local machine I'm (windows 7) is 192.168.1.150 and I'm working on my website on a Linux share (samba) - his ip is 192.168.1.151, i made a share and did "map network directory" so now my web root is on drive Z:\ ... is there a way to install xdebug on the remote machine and debug Drupal while I'm working & developing in my windows machine? Or it has to sit on the local host in order to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

1. .test file are to be used by Simpltest module.
   You can join drupal.org QA by installing Simpletest module and using patches available at http://qa.drupal.org
   Most patches create a .test file automatically so users can participate in tests.
2. If you do not need to participate in QA, you can ignore these files. If disk space is an issue, delete them.